# How to update column values in a spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to load data from Elasticsearch to Mongo DB using Spark.

I'm collecting the data from ES into a dataframe and then pushing the DF into Mongo DB.

Now, I have a column named '_id' in my dataframe which has String value
i.e., _id: "abcd12345"

I would now like to modify this columnvalue to mongo ObjectId type and then push to Mongo DB,
i.e., _id: ObjectId("abcd12345")

I have tried achieving it using the following spark code, but I find no luck in getting what I want.

```
    import spark.implicits._
   val df = spark.read
  .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
  .option("query", esQuery)
  .option("pushdown", true)
  .option("scroll.size", Config.ES_SCROLL_SIZE)
  .load(Config.ES_RESOURCE)
  .withColumn("_id", $"_metadata".getItem("_id"))
  .drop("_metadata")

   df("_id") = new ObjectId(df("_id").toString()) // error
```

Expect the resultant DataFrame to have '_id' column value as,
_id: ObjectId("abc12345") instead of _id: "abc12345"

Any help is appreciated. I'm really blocked with this issue.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve using `df("_id") = new ObjectId(df("_id").toString())`

Comment: As I have already mentioned, I'm trying to convert the String value stored "_id" column to a Mongo ObjectId datatype.

Comment: did you try this `.withColumn("_id", new ObjectId($"_metadata".getItem("_id")))`

Comment: Yes, with that in place I get the following error,Type Mismatch : Expected: Column Actual: ObjectId

Comment: `.withColumn("_id", lit(new ObjectId($"_metadata".getItem("_id"))))`